# Shared Python Packages Among Docker Containers

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose, mlops

I've multiple docker containers that host some flask apps which runs some machine learning services. Let's say container 1 is using pytorch, and container 2 is also using pytorch. When I build image, both pytorch take up some size on disk. For some reason, we split these 2 services into different containers, if I insist on this way, is it possible to only build pytorch once so that both container can import it? Thanks in advance, appreciate any help and suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

You can build one docker image and install pytorch on it. Then use that image as base image for those two codes. In this way, pytorch only takes hard space once. And you save time no installing pytorch twice.

You can also build only one image, copy your codes in two different directories,
for example /app1 and /app2. Then in your docker compose, change work directory for each app.